# simulating login process with recaptcha (generating tokens)

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha, captcha

I am trying to access a site that need login credentials and solving a recaptcha v2, I am using python requests library to do that.

I am using the anticaptcha api to solve the captcha, and I now have the "g-recaptcha-response", but when I get to the login request, using regular browser and network tab in the DevTools, I see the login request has payload with 2 extra tokens (beside other static data like username and password,..)
these tokens are:

__RequestVerificationToken 
RecaptchaToken

__RequestVerificationToken (1yvl3JbNqqll88O3pg7-Qdn8_QC8hcQdUIyCLaAno7xNCg2ql-rycdgC75Xz1AKRlghiuOzE_XZOrJiBTUz25cLOf1M1)

---

RecaptchaToken (03AOLTBLT9huh3hlzUWneKS-LDVRr0U4_4N8OvsV2dAY6L-DduwTXTdHGFEaLJKzqyNW6w3SAFoKo_hQWq2qecRTsca0IrTYR0pExziAh4eWsDjCj-NdhwBnaVQwo97QaE6q0aKZAIMNx6efET9869Jv_x75KRZX9esLxVY0VT_Zo93ha-iX_4B7h1Si9aicVi59ldaCrCTCClb7SkAw7fYnf_0s1_uY1BfpkcylvHgoGeGXLUdJ91kn_wV0b2USCRkeFb8m9AAS5Cy6avDllc4cmZ8oDH5c9KedQ1kv3Tt03K0-q_4V3BRy0zPV25L6h7qt4PTqT9kRRIQfMI_AvoNbn78kD8mXAJNA)

---

what are those extra tokens? how I get them?
I searched in all process loaded while solving the captcha in the browser, no mention for these values or even the arguments names.

Comment: One of them is in the source (#recaptcha-token maybe?) and one comes from the anticaptcha api.

Comment: __RequestVerificationToken this one from the source, but RecaptchaToken this one is unknown for me till now

Comment: Post the html and I will point it out to you.